# How to create a boxplot with two variables (dead and alive) having the same y axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataset corresponding to the efficacy of different nematicide treatments.
My variables are Dead nematodes and Alive nematodes.
Here is the dataset:

```
Rep               Treatment Dead Alive
1    1             OR-454 (5%)   42    32
2    2             OR-454 (5%)   64    14
3    3             OR-454 (5%)   42     4
4    4             OR-454 (5%)   54    18
5    5             OR-454 (5%)   57    20
6    6             OR-454 (5%)   60    17
7    7             OR-454 (5%)   66     9
8    8             OR-454 (5%)   52    14
9    9             OR-454 (5%)   65    12
10  10             OR-501 (5%)   63     5
11  11             OR-501 (5%)   62    10
12  12             OR-501 (5%)   54    16
13  13             OR-501 (5%)   55    12
14  14             OR-501 (5%)   97    13
15  15             OR-501 (5%)   63     4
16  16             OR-501 (5%)   61     7
17  17             OR-501 (5%)   62     1
18  18             OR-501 (5%)   70     5
19  19            OR-501 (10%)   62     6
20  20            OR-501 (10%)   67     5
21  21            OR-501 (10%)   73     7
22  22            OR-501 (10%)   68     4
23  23            OR-501 (10%)   81    14
24  24            OR-501 (10%)   73     7
25  25 OR-454 (5%)+OR-501 (5%)   80     8
26  26 OR-454 (5%)+OR-501 (5%)   62    10
27  27 OR-454 (5%)+OR-501 (5%)   70     0
28  28 OR-454 (5%)+OR-501 (5%)   64     7
29  29 OR-454 (5%)+OR-501 (5%)   67    11
30  30 OR-454 (5%)+OR-501 (5%)   60    13
31  31 OR-454 (5%)+OR-501 (5%)   63    12
32  32 OR-454 (5%)+OR-501 (5%)   64     7
33  33 OR-454 (5%)+OR-501 (5%)   71     5
34  34           OR-512-A (5%)   68     0
35  35           OR-512-A (5%)   67     5
36  36           OR-512-A (5%)   86     1
37  37           OR-512-A (5%)   66     0
38  38           OR-512-A (5%)   88     1
39  39           OR-512-A (5%)   60     0
40  40           OR-512-A (5%)   41     2
41  41           OR-512-A (5%)   61     5
42  42           OR-512-A (5%)   39     5
43  43           OR-512-B (5%)   57     2
44  44           OR-512-B (5%)   63     1
45  45           OR-512-B (5%)   75     8
46  46           OR-512-B (5%)   58     2
47  47           OR-512-B (5%)   63     4
48  48           OR-512-B (5%)   83     2
49  49        Afromyl (Oxamyl)   53     7
50  50        Afromyl (Oxamyl)   50     8
51  51        Afromyl (Oxamyl)   40    18
52  52        Afromyl (Oxamyl)   60    22
53  53        Afromyl (Oxamyl)   46    14
54  54        Afromyl (Oxamyl)   51    15
55  55        Afromyl (Oxamyl)   39    25
56  56        Afromyl (Oxamyl)   59    16
57  57        Afromyl (Oxamyl)   42    12
58  58                 Control    3    74
59  59                 Control    2    70
60  60                 Control    4    56
61  61                 Control    2    78
62  62                 Control    5    90
63  63                 Control    3    62
64  64                 Control    2    66
65  65                 Control    3    78
66  66                 Control    2    62
```

I would like to generate a boxplot containing both Dead and Alive nematodes for each treatment side by side.

All I was able to do was to generate boxplots for either dead or alive, but not both together in the same graph.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please can you include the code you have written

Comment: Hello @RichardTelford, here's the code I used to plot the Dead nematodes: ggplot(data, aes(x = Treatment, y = Dead, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic()

Comment: Maybe plot proportion alive against treatment

Comment: Thanks @RichardTelford, might end up doing that to simplify.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to covert your data first to "long" format. For example, using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`.

You can then have one column for `N` or number of nematodes, and another column for `Status` (Alive or Dead).

You can also use `facet_wrap` to group the boxplots by `Treatment`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Dead, Alive), values_to = "N", names_to = "Status") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Status, y = N, color = Treatment)) + 
    geom_boxplot() + 
    theme_classic() +
    facet_wrap(~Treatment)
```

**Plot**

[image: side-by-side plot of data in long format]

Alternatively, you can calculate mortality rate (%) and plot that instead.

You can relevel the factor `Treatment` so that Control is at the beginning (or end).

```
data %>%
  mutate(mortality_rate = 100 * Dead / (Dead + Alive),
         Treatment = fct_relevel(Treatment, "Control")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = mortality_rate, color = Treatment)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    ylab("Percent Mortality") +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

**Plot**

[image: plot of mortality rate]

Comment: Appreciate your input, @Ben. Might end up plotting %mortality instead. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RobM See edited answer with additional plot of % mortality

Comment: Thanks for the fct_relevel function. I usually add a letters column in excel, to adjust treatment order. Quite primitive, I know. But hey, I'm learning :)